# Convert Python partition generator to Java

Tags: java, python, combinatorics, code-conversion

I am trying to convert the following partition generator from Python into Java and not getting the expected result:

Python:

```
def accelAsc(n):
    a = [0 for i in range(n + 1)]
    k = 1
    a[0] = 0
    y = n - 1
    while k != 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        k -= 1
        while 2*x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        l = k + 1
        while x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            a[l] = y
            yield a[:k + 2]
            x += 1
            y -= 1
        a[k] = x + y
        y = x + y - 1
        yield a[:k + 1]
```

My Java:

```
public static void partition( int n ){
    int[] a = new int[ n + 1 ];
    int k = 1;
    int y = n - 1;
    while( k != 0 ){
        int x = a[k - 1] + 1;
        k -= 1;
        while( 2*x <= y ){
            a[k] = x;
            y -= x;
            k += 1;
        }
        int l = k + 1;
        while( x <= y ){
            a[k] = x;
            a[l] = y;
            for( int xValue = 0; xValue <= k; xValue++ ) System.out.print( a[xValue + 2] );
            System.out.println();
            x += 1;
            y -= 1;
        }
        a[k] = x + y;
        y = x + y - 1;
        for( int xValue = 0; xValue <= k; xValue++ ) System.out.print( a[xValue + 1] );
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Calling this with an argument of 5 results in the following printout:

```
1110
1121
132
22
42
2
3
```

which is incorrect.

Comment: For starters, `a[:k + 2]` means "all items from a[0] up to a[k+2]", but your equivalent System.out.print is in a for loop that goes from a[2] to a[k+2].

Comment: You should answer your own question then check it off as answered as it is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's comment leads to the answer:

replace

```
for( int xValue = 0; xValue <= k; xValue++ ) System.out.print( a[xValue + 2] );
```

with

```
for( int xValue = 0; xValue < k + 2; xValue++ ) System.out.print( a[xValue] );
```

and

replace

```
for( int xValue = 0; xValue <= k; xValue++ ) System.out.print( a[xValue + 1] );
```

with

```
for( int xValue = 0; xValue < k + 1; xValue++ ) System.out.print( a[xValue] );
```